# What does 'placement' mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'placement' mean in context and how it's connected with next sentense 'They were told the Obamas had seen the movie a few days earlier.

> Filmmakers Steven Bognar and Julia Reichert said they learned of the
>   Obamas' interest in the film as they were discussing **placement** of
>   American Factory with Netflix. They were told the Obamas had seen the
>   movie a few days earlier.

Answer (score 2):

One of the meanings of "placement" is the act of putting something in a particular place.

The "putting" and the "place" are metaphorical here, as it means to put the film in the Netflix system for them to distribute, rather than with another movie company.

American Factory appears to be the name of the movie.